# Alternative coordinates for the complex plane $\mathrm{Re}[e^{-is}z]=a$, $\mathrm{Re}[e^{-it}z]=b $

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

I am defining coordintes on $\mathbb{C}$ using a "generalized" real and imaginary part.

Here $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

\begin{eqnarray*} \mathrm{Re}[e^{-is}z]&=&a \\
\mathrm{Re}[e^{-it}z]&=&b 
\end{eqnarray*}

Is it possible to solve the system of equations without "brute force" ?

Write $z = x + iy$ and the system becomes,

\begin{eqnarray*} x \cos s + y \sin s&=&a \\
x \cos t + y \sin t&=&b 
\end{eqnarray*}

Solve for $x,y$ using Cramer's Rule:

$$ x = -\frac{\left|\begin{array}{cc}   a &  \sin s \\
 b &  \sin t\end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{cc}   \cos s &  \sin s \\
 \cos t &  \sin t\end{array}\right|} = \frac{a \sin t - b \sin s}{\cos (s-t)}
 \hspace{0.25in} y = \frac{\left|\begin{array}{cc} \cos s &  a  \\
 \cos t & b \end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{cc}   \cos s &  \sin s \\
 \cos t &  \sin t\end{array}\right|}= \frac{b \cos s - a \sin t}{\cos (s-t)}$$

This this formula have a geometric meaning?  Could this number have been found without using Cramer's rule? Or combining into a single equation with complex numbers?